# JS/CSS How to change background color in middle of transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create a flipboard effect for some divs (ie: One side is white, the other is black). And right now I have this:

```js
setInterval(function () {
 document.getElementById('test').classList.toggle('flipped')
}, 1000)
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
}
.flipped {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

But I'm not sure how to have the background stay white, until the rotation is "flat" and then change color. Any ideas?

Comment: You can give `transition` to the `#test` as `transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.45, 1.47)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adjust the transition of the background:

```js
setInterval(function () {
 document.getElementById('test').classList.toggle('flipped')
}, 1000)
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 
    transform 1s linear,
    background 0s 0.5s linear; /*change imediately after 0.5s*/
}

.flipped {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

But better rely on animation than using transtion with JS:

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  animation:flip 1s infinite alternate linear;
}


@keyframes flip{
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); 
    background:#fff; 
  }
  49.5% {
    background:#fff;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    background:yellow;
  }
  to {
   transform: rotateX(180deg);
    background:yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: On my FF it desynchronises into an ugly randomness.

Comment: @Kaiido true, it's buggy on my side too, only working good in Chrome ... the setinterval isn't the way to go, I added another way.

Comment: Interesting bug... With an interval of `1016` it works well in FF. With an `ease` timing-function it works well in FF. They probably have something wrong in their linear timing function (like it's on late-frame or something). Yeah, [waiting a full frame](https://jsfiddle.net/ug0vcrLz/) is needed, [waiting for next frame](https://jsfiddle.net/ug0vcrLz/1/) is not enough.

Comment: @Kaiido And I am not able to trigger the bug all the time .. in most of the cases it run fine without issue.

Comment: Ah I can repro all the time after first iteration.

Comment: This is the best solution for my needs. The interval was just for demonstration purposes, the divs will actually flip on an as-needed basis. For clarity, this is what I was wanting it for: http://jsfiddle.net/therks/tmru5ay7

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below structure for achieving this

```js
setInterval(function () {
 document.getElementById('test').classList.toggle('flipped')
}, 1000)
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 1000px; 
}
#test {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#test:before,#test:after {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#test:before {
  content:"";
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
}
#test:after {
  content:"";
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.flipped {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div id="test"></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did ? :)

Comment: Unfortunately Safari has its backface-visibilty completely buggy... (And Chrome does the same every now and then)

Comment: @Arkellys I made a div(#test) which has one side black and other is white with after and before  pseudo-elements and then rotate it when .flipped class added to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation to set the last frame as black;

```js
setInterval(function () {
 document.getElementById('test').classList.toggle('flipped')
}, 1000)
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 1s;
}

.flipped {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  animation: changeColor 0.3s 0.7s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
0%, 100%{background:black}
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```